# Java method to log in from user from hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, methods

I learning Java, SQL, Hibernate and I must make a method to log in as user from MySQL DB. I'm trying write the code but I can't compare String from scanner and from DB. I don't have Spring for now.

```
import com.sda.util.HibernateUtil;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserLogging {
    EntityManager em = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().createEntityManager();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


    public void logging() {


        System.out.println("Enter email:");
        String userInputEmail = scanner.nextLine();



        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select from user u where u.email = :?", User.class);
        query.setParameter("?", userInputEmail);


        if (userInputEmail.equals(query.toString())) {

            System.out.println("You are logged in.");
        } else
            System.out.println("Login failed.");


        em.getTransaction().commit();

    }
}
```

Comment: `query.toString()`--Your query is not the _result_ of the query. You need to execute the query and look at the result.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do to learn a new language/technology is to just try out stuff and to figure it out yourself!

E.g. try using a debugger - If you don't know what that is or how to use it, just watch a tutorial online :) This helps a ton on finding out, what exactly is wrong with your code -> Thus helping you narrowing down your problem even more, so you can e.g. google more specific questions.

But to answer your question, and maybe a few more:

#### Transactions

Generally, you don't have to create a transaction for each query; As long as it's just a SELECT. (You're not changing anything in the DB, which means you're not altering any information; Nothing happens to your data, even if your program were to crash).

Speaking of transactions: `transaction.commit()` does not execute your query. It just commits the transaction; Meaning, it's not rolled back.

#### The query itself

As stated previously, `transaction.commit()` doesn't execute any queries.

And spoiler alert: `query.toString()` doesn't do it either.

You should use `query.getResultList()` and then you're able to iterate over it by e.g. using a while loop.

#### Cleaner syntax

You can also link multiple things together like this:

```
em.createNativeQuery("...", User.class)
    .setParameter(...)
    .getResultList();
```